# Contact Form 7 Radio Button *Required Not Working

Tags: wordpress, radio-button, contact-form-7

CF7 should automatically require a field selected for radio buttons.

However, in my contact form, I can skip radio buttons.

I tried to include the * symbol but isn't working (as suppose to).

Any ideas on how to make CF7 radio required?

```
<p class="cf7h1">Approximately how much traffic do you generate per month?</p> <br />
<p class="cf7subh1">It won't be shared.</p>
[radio radio-traffic default:1 use_label_element "Under 10,000" "10,000 to 25,000" "25,000 to 50,000" "Above 50,000"]
```

Comment: I know I have the "default:1" value in the code.

However, I would like to display: "The field is required." as per normal * behaviour

Comment: try to put this [radio radio-traffic "Under 10,000" "10,000 to 25,000" "25,000 to 50,000" "Above 50,000"]

Comment: @DipakDholakiya I did and still the same behaviour :/

Answer (score 1):

*radio* represents a group of radio buttons ( in HTML). Note that there is no required version of radio (“**radio***”). The reason Contact Form 7 doesn’t provide “radio*” is because a radio button is a required field by nature.

Check the HTML spec document https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio.